# Is it possible to set the response data to the state when I press the edit button using React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I'm currently new developing in react js. I have problem regarding passing the result to the each textbox when i click the edit button. I currently use the Bootstrap table V1 http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/.

Is it possible to pass the response data to each input textbox when i click the button.?

I will share to you guys my sample work that I already done today.

**My Function:**

```
    function EditUser(row,cell) {
    axios.get('/api/geteditUser/'+cell).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}

function action_format(cell,row) {
    return <div><button onClick={() => EditUser(row,cell)}  className="btn btn-primary" style={{fontSize:14}} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i className="far fa-edit" style={{fontSize:14}}></i></button> <button style={{fontSize:14}}  className="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i className="fas fa-trash-alt" style={{fontSize:14}}></i></button></div>
}
```

**Bootstrap Table:**

```
    <BootstrapTable data={this.state.list_user} pagination={ true } search options={ this.options } striped hover version='4'>
                            <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>Id</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='email'>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='role' dataFormat={format}>Role</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='status'>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
                            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='id' dataFormat={action_format}>Action</TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
```

**My Modal:**

```
<form onSubmit={this.UpdateDriverStatus}>    
<div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="row">

        <div className="col-md-6">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" value={this.props.setUserid} className="form-control"></input>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control"></input>
        </div>

    </div>
    <br/>
    <div className="row">

        <div className="col-md-6">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" className="form-control"></input>

        </div>

        <div className="col-md-6">

        <label>Status</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control"></input>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<center><button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary col-md-6">Update</button></center>
```

Comment: You could save the response in the state and pass it into the components during rendering?

Comment: yah. what i mean if i click the button edit, the response data that I click will pass into each corresponding textbox.

Comment: Maybe add a Boolean to your state (passResponse), which can be toggled with the click. And if this.state.passResponse is true, you pass the response. If not you pass undefined.

Comment: can you give the sample for that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to only pass the response, if the button is clicked, you have to save that within the state like this:

```
function action_format(cell,row) {
    return <div><button onClick={() => {EditUser(row,cell)}; this.setState({passResponse: true}} ...}
```

This will save whether the response data should be pushed into the input elements.
Now to actually push the data in your render function:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.passResponse ? this.state.response: this.props.setUserid} className="form-control"></input>
```

You should toggle the passResponse to false, if you are done with the editing.
Hope this helps. Happy coding.